# Angular 2 unable to resolve lint errors for http call

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this api function:

```
getBrands(params?: any): Observable<IBrand[]> {
  return this.http.get(Host + endpoints.brands, params)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IBrand[])
    .catch((error: any) => {

      this.notifications.show({message: 'Kunde inte hämta märken', theme: 'danger'});

      return error || 'Server fel';
    });
}
```

It works fine by getting the data from the external api, but I get two lint errors which I cannot resolve for the life of me.

First one is this:

```
Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IBrand[]>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IBrand[]'.
    Property 'find' is missing in type '{}'.
```

And the second one is `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` which comes from this line`.map((res: Response) => res.json() as IBrand[])`.

Why do I get these errors and how can I resolve them?

**EDIT:**

`IBrand` interface as requested:

```
export class IBrand {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
  image?: string;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `return <Observable<IBrand[]>> this.http.get(Host + endpoints.bran..` ?

Comment: Could you  post your code for `IBrand` ?

Comment: which IDE are you using, sometimes restarting IDE works, or try to return promise using ToPromise() extension by rxjs rather than observable, or did you import 'rxjs/Rx'; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it didn't like the `.catch` returning what it did, instead I had to change it to look like this:

```
getBrands(params?: any): Observable<IBrand[]> {
  return this.http.get(Host + endpoints.brands, params)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IBrand[])
    .catch((error: any) => {

      this.notifications.show({message: 'Kunde inte hämta märken', theme: 'danger'});

      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server fel');
    });
}
```

And the error goes away.